# I have svgwrite installed, but I get error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svgwrite' MacBook Pro Ventura 13.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-ventura, svgwrite

When I run my python code using svgwrite I get an error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svgwrite'`.

I have svgwrite installed and when I tried to install it again with `pip install svgwrite`, I get this message:
`Requirement already satisfied: svgwrite in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/svgwrite-1.3.1-py2.7.egg Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.1 (from svgwrite) Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyparsing/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyparsing>=2.0.1 (from svgwrite) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyparsing>=2.0.1 (from svgwrite)`. I'm using Python 3 and that seems to be for Python 2.7 version. What can I do to fix it? I'm using a Macbook Pro with latest Ventura version.

Comment: try installing with `pip3`, then make sure you are using the correct python enviroment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.